# How do I print a line following a line containing certain text in a saved file in Python?

Tags: python, html, string, parsing

I have written a Python program to find the carrier of a cell phone given the number. It downloads the source of http://www.whitepages.com/carrier_lookup?carrier=other&number_0=1112223333&response=1 (where 1112223333 is the phone number to lookup) and saves this as carrier.html. In the source, the carrier is in the line after the [div class="carrier_result"] tag. (switch in < and > for [ and ], as stackoverflow thought I was trying to format using the html and would not display it.)

My program currently searches the file and finds the line containing the div tag, but now I need a way to store the next line after that as a string. My current code is: http://pastebin.com/MSDN0vbC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you really want to be doing is parsing the HTML properly. Use the BeautifulSoup library - it's wonderful at doing so.

Sample code:

```
import urllib2, BeautifulSoup

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders[0] = ('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.1')

response = opener.open('http://www.whitepages.com/carrier_lookup?carrier=other&number_0=1112223333&response=1').read()

bs = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(response)
print bs.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'carrier_result'})[0].next.strip()
```

Comment: Could you please explain how to do this with beautifulsoup? I looked at their website and was confused.

Comment: Be wary of 'working around' a website's controls - this may draw their ire.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the advice too. I'll keep that in mind, though I'll probably have to stick with it this way as I have yet to find another way to find a carrier given the cellphone number.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a HTML parser such as [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) instead.

Comment: Could you explain to me how to do this with either of those?

Comment: `soup.find('div', {'class': 'carrier_result'}).text`

Answer (score 2):

to get the next line, you can use

```
htmlsource = open('carrier.html', 'r')
for line in htmlsource:
    if '<div class="carrier_result">' in line:
         nextline = htmlsource.next()
         print nextline
```

A "better" way is to split on `</div>`, then get the things you want, as sometimes the stuff you want can occur all in one line. So using next() if give wrong result.eg

```
data=open("carrier.html").read().split("</div>")
for item in data:
    if '<div class="carrier_result">' in item:
       print item.split('<div class="carrier_result">')[-1].strip()
```

by the way, if its possible, try to use Python's own web module, like `urllib`, `urllib2` instead of calling external `wget`.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was the only one that did not use beautifulsoup, but since so many other answers did I might try it both ways. 

I tried using urllib, but it did not work. This is because the website only allows views from certain browsers (and this is the reason why I had to call wget with a certain browser agent). If there is a way to use urllib and faking a browser agent, please tell me as I would much rather not have to call wget.

Comment: Heh, I noticed that too and am about to post a workaround... be careful as this may piss them off.

Comment: if you look at the urllib2 documentation http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html, way below the page, there are examples of adding http headers to your requests. Not sure if it will work for you, but you can give it a try. As for using BeautifulSoup and stuff, i believe ideally you should use it, but i also believe that if the problem you are trying to solve is simple enough, there is no need to use them. Just using Python in builts will do

Comment: Your answer was good, but MikeyB's is more efficient and makes good use of BeautifulSoup.